# My form inside a modal is not working PHP HTML

Tags: php

This is my code, I was supposed to get the inputted value in db and php tag isnt working.. It is not also redirecting to "myorders.php"; My form inside is not working.. Thank you.. Really need some help :(((

```
<div class="container">
      <form method="post">
        <h2>Enter your Pin Number</h2>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Enter your Pin Number</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body text-center">

                <input type="password" id="first-name" required="required" class="form-control" name="pin">
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="submit3" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Confirm Pin</button>
              </div>
            </div>             
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- START OF PHP -->
          <?php include ('connectdb.php');
          if(isset($_POST['submit3']))
          {    
             $pin = $_POST["pin"];
             $pww = "123";
             if ($pin!=$pww) {
               echo "WRONG PIN.. TRY AGAIN..";
             }
             else{
                header('Location: myorders.php');
             }
          } // SUBMIT 
          ?>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: maybe because of this `data-dismiss="modal"` on your button ?

Comment: yeah, try removing `data-dismiss="modal"` from your submit button.

Comment: Wow thanks so much!! :) helped a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, remove `data-dismiss="modal"` from your submit button. `data-dismiss="modal"` is used to close the modal dialog. You already have it here

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
```

Comment: Yes :) will do!